# Limit of $n^{th}$ root of logarithm

Tags: real-analysis

Does the limit as $n \rightarrow \infty $ $(\log{n})^{\frac{1}{n}}$ exist?

Suppose it does then we have a way to compute it. Take a sub-sequence by substituting $2^n$ in place of $n$. We get $$n^{\frac{1}{2^n}}(\log{2})^{\frac{1}{2^n}}$$

Which ofcourse is one.

**Edit :** Now $1 < \log{n} < n$. Therefore $1 < (\log{n})^{\frac{1}{n}} < n^{\frac{1}{n}}$. By sandwitch lemma the limit should have been 1.

Is that alright?

Comment: You are correct in stating that if the limit exists, then that is a valid means of computing it.

Comment: limit as n approaches what??

Comment: @ Rememberme Its $n \rightarrow \infty$ Please check the edit.

Comment: Why is it "of course zero"? $n^{1/2^n}\to1$, and $(\log2)^{1/2^n}\to1$.

Comment: Your sandwich is tastily correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\log(n)^{1/n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\exp(\log(\log(n)^{1/n}))=\lim_{n\to\infty}\exp\Big(\frac{\log(\log(n))}{n}\Big)=\exp(0)=1.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $n > 3$ so that $\log n > 1$ and we then have the inequality $$1 < \log n < n$$ for all positive integers $n > 3$. Thus we get $$1 < (\log n)^{1/n} < n^{1/n}$$ and we know that $n^{1/n} \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$ hence by Squeeze theorem $(\log n)^{1/n} \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$.

There are many ways to show that $n^{1/n} \to 1$. For example we can set $n^{1/n} = 1 + h$ so that (via Binomial Theorem) $$n = (1 + h)^{n} > \frac{n(n - 1)}{2}h^{2}$$ or $$0 < h^{2} < \frac{2}{n - 1}$$ and hence $h^{2} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. Since $h > 0$ this means that $h \to 0$ and hence $n^{1/n} = 1 + h \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$.